# warning "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, angular

html code:

```
 <form action="{{url}}"> 
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-
click="goToProdPage()" value="Resume">
           </form>
```

Angular Code:

```
    $scope.goToProdPage = function(){
    if(id){
        $scope.url = "#/"+id+"/cpq";
    console.log("done   "+id);
    $state.go("cpq");
    } 
}
```

Please ignore the id because i put only half code.
I already used $(document.body).append(form); 
and it solved the issue but after adding it now its show bellow error on console

> angular.js:14362 ReferenceError: form is not defined
>       at b.$scope.findUser.$scope.goToProdPage (login.js:44)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15197), :4:156)
>       at e (angular.js:26808)
>       at b.$eval (angular.js:18017)
>       at b.$apply (angular.js:18117)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (angular.js:26813)
>       at dg (angular.js:3617)
>       at HTMLInputElement.d (angular.js:3605)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do here. But my opinion is that you should use a more an Angular-way of handling forms...

```
<form ng-submit="mySubmit()">
    <input type="submit" value="Send form">
</form>
```

Now you can write a function in your controller handling the form's submit.

```
this.mySubmit = mySubmit;

function mySubmit() {
    // Check here if the url exists
    // ...or what to do when submitting the form...
    // this.goToProdPage();
}
```

A more detailed example or extra information could help me better understand the issue :-)

Comment: actully i want to route from "http://localhost:3000/#/login" to "http://localhost:3000/#/fbfce1c0-abd4-11e7-b3c4-8ba82fba00a7/cpq". with the form action. the GUID is change every time when i click on submit form

Comment: You should do something like: ```function mySubmit() { if(id) { $state.go('/'+id+'/cpq'); } }```

Answer (score 1):

first remove type submit from button and put id in form

```
<form id="myform" action="{{url}}"> 
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-
click="goToProdPage()" value="Resume">
</form>
```

and in function goToProdPage() after all the processing is completed trigger the form submit with jquery

```
$scope.goToProdPage = function(){
    if(id){
       $scope.url = "#/"+id+"/cpq";
       console.log("done   "+id);
       $state.go("cpq");
       $('#myform').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer .but its not working :(.. actually i want to route from "http://localhost:3000/#/login" to "http://localhost:3000/#/fbfce1c0-abd4-11e7-b3c4-8ba82fba00a7/cpq". with the form action. the GUID is change every time when i click on submit form